# String assignment by each element

Tags: c++

I wrote a string assignment in c++, but I don't know why it output s[0], while output none of s?
The code is following, and the output is: h**hello*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string s;
    s[0] = 'h';
    s[1] = 'i';
    string s2;
    s2="hello";
    cout <<s[0]<<"*"<< s << "*" << s2<<"*";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `s` is empty. You cannot access any of its characters with operator `[]`, because there are none.

Comment: Assigning to `s[pos]` when `pos >= s.size()` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Change `s[0] = 'h';` to `s.at(0) = 'h';` so the program can die gracefully.

Comment: Technically, accessing `s[pos]` when `pos == s.size()` is not UB since C++11, as it accesses the string's required null terminator. But it is UB if the value being written to that `pos` is anything other than `'\0'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `std::string`, operator[] is only valid to index into existing data of the string.  It does *not* cause the string to grow, it simply goes out of bounds if the string isn't already that size.  To append to a string, you have several options, but to append single chars like you're doing, you'd do this:

```
int main(){
    std::string s;
    s += 'h';
    s += 'i';
    ...
```

Each application of operator += causes the size of the string to grow.